# Change layout of EditText on state "selected"

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, drawable, android-drawable

I am trying to obtain a EditText changing it's colors and layout when the user clicks on it to type something, and I do that with a custom drawable, but the attributes `android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="true">` don't work at all, meaning that they don't get called.

`EditText`:

```
 <EditText android:id="@+id/field_user_info" android:hint="Nome e Cognome"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp" android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:padding="8dp" android:maxLines="1"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_account_edittext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColorHint="@color/textHint"/>
```

`custom_account_edittext` drawable:

```
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <!--<solid android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"/>-->
            <!--android:color="#ffffff" -->
            <solid android:color="@color/account_grey_300" />
            <stroke android:width="0.8dip"
                android:color="@color/account_grey_400"/>
            <corners android:radius="2dip" /> <!--android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"--><!--android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp"--><!--android:topLeftRadius="7dp"--><!--android:topRightRadius="7dp"/>-->
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_enabled="true"  android:state_focused="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <!--<solid android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"/>-->
            <!--android:color="#ffffff" -->
            <solid android:color="@color/white" />
            <stroke android:width="1dip"
                android:color="@color/cardview_blu_color600"/>
            <corners android:radius="2dip" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

My problem is that I always visualize the default layout (the first item).
Why do the items `<item android:state_enabled="true"  android:state_focused="true">` don't get activated at all?

How can I customize my `TextView` states?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="true">
```

EDIT:

Try this and check if the background color is changed when clicked on edittext

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="#f07c01"
        /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item
    android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="#c099cc00"
        /> <!-- focused -->
    <item
        android:drawable="#0d91a8"
        /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

Comment: thanks I've changed it to `<item android:state_enabled="true"  android:state_focused="true">` but it doesn't work...

Comment: I don't know how but now it's working. It turns out that either you use the attribute `android:drawable="@color/white"` or the `<item>` tag. Only one of them is going to work. But I don't understand how my code is now different from what I have originally done! 
First trial: http://pastie.org/private/lvbmk3mbci8lwkznlrfvg

Last edit: http://pastie.org/private/lfs4uphkels0fyvgffolg

Comment: I've tried again and the order of the two changes the result! why is that?

Comment: Yes, if the item with `state_focused` and `state_enabled` is the first item, then it works, otherwise, it doesn't....It also work if there is another item containing `state_pressed` in the beginning, but it seems as if the default item must be in the end